# Where is a good to call actions for fail and success in react-redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I have a question about `redux`.

Now, I'm building my mobile app following [redux advanced tutorial](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions).

The tutorial says that you have to create 3 actions each 1 function so I have created 3 actions for sign-in function like below:

```
requestSignIn
requestSignInSuccess
requestSignInFailure
```

However, I don't understand where the app should call them from.

Now, in my app, the app calls `requestSignInSuccess` and `requestSignInFailure` in `requestSignIn`.

This is my action code:

```
export const REQUEST_SIGN_IN = 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN';
export const REQUEST_SIGN_IN_FAILURE = 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN_FAILURE';
export const REQUEST_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS = 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS';

import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

export function requestSignIn() {
  // start sign in function
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
    .then(response => {
      // success, so call requestSignInSuccess() to change state
      requestSignInSuccess(response.user);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // fail, so call requestSignInFailure() to change state
      requestSignInFailure(error);
    })

}

function requestSignInSuccess(user) {
  // save user info into state in reducer
  return {
    type: 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS'
    payload: user
  }
}

function requestSignInFailure(error) {
  // save error message into state in reducer
  return {
    type: 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN_FAILURE'
    payload: error
  }
}
```

[Questions]

- Am I following the `redux` tutorial correctly? (The app calls `requestSignInFailure` and `requestSignInSuccess` in `requestSignIn` function, is it good?)
- If I want the app to have `isLoading` flag into state, which action should change the flag?

Comment: may be in wrong authentication can give a response which is not comes in requestSignInSuccess. so there you have to check the response then dispatch the actions accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to answer one by one your questions.

> Am I following the `redux` tutorial correctly?

Yes, you are on the right track, just few steps missing. The below explanation is for class based components.

Technically if you created actions - just like above in your question - then what you need to do is dispatching them in the component in order to use.

1. Firstly need to dispatch the actions in `mapDispatchToProps`.
2. Then need to connect the component - to call `requestSignIn` action - with the `Redux` store.
3. Pass the created `mapDispatchToProps` to connect as the second parameter.

Please find the following example below:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

// ... other imports

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
     constructor (props) {
         super(props);
     }

     // ... component code
     // ... obviously this is just an example component for representation

     render() {
         return (
             <>
                 <a onClick={props.requestSignIn()}>Request Sign In</a>
             </>
         )
     }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators({ requestSignIn }, dispatch);
};


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent);
```

> If I want the app to have `isLoading` flag into state, which action should change the flag?

I would create in the reducer a new property called `isLoading` just like below:

```
const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
};

export default (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
         case 'ENABLE_LOADING':
              return {
                   ...state,
                   isLoading: true,
              };

         case 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS':
              return {
                   ...state,
                   isLoading: false,
              };

         case 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN_FAILURE':
              return {
                   ...state,
                   isLoading: false,
              };

         // ... other actions
    }
}
```

In your `requestSignIn` action need to trigger `ENABLE_LOADING` once you start fetching the data one line before `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(EMAIL, PASSWORD)` then it will hopefully work for you. Just like how you did with `REQUEST_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS` and `REQUEST_SIGN_IN_FAILURE`.

To access the reducer's properties you need to use `mapStateToProps` further.

In functional component case you need to use `useDispatch` to call the created actions:

> This hook returns a reference to the dispatch function from the Redux store. You may use it to dispatch actions as needed.

And to access the data from the store there is a hook called `useSelector`:

> Allows you to extract data from the Redux store state, using a selector function.

**Quick summary:**

If you are looking for a fully working example with `useSelector` and `useDispatch` in a functional component then take a look at this git repository:

https://github.com/norbitrial/react-redux-loading-data-example

In the repository you will find a nice representation of a fake API call which loads data into a table with a loader indicator, just like what you need from your question.

In case of further interest in more details please find the below links which are pretty useful:

1. [Connect: Dispatching Actions with mapDispatchToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#connect-dispatching-actions-with-mapdispatchtoprops)
2. [Connect: Extracting Data with mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#connect-extracting-data-with-mapstatetoprops)
3. [Dispatching actions with `useDispatch()` for functional component](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch)
4. [Extract data with `useSelector()` for functional component](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector)

I hope this helps, let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Try using redux-thunk middleware to handle promises in the actions. You will get a fullfilled, pending (your loading) and failure actions for every promises.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right but to keep code clean and readable i would advise you to take all type variables out of component, create action folder inside `src` -> create file `types.js` (or any name you want) and move all variables to it. you can do same with `requestSignInFailure` and `requestSignInSuccess` (keep action related stuff in your actions folder. (UNLESS you are not using react hooks because you must use useDispatch in React component funcion, not in pure function)). and to dispatch data to store you must use dispatch (I assume you use `connect` method while exporting component) and if you pass your action to connect as second argument function will get second function inside with argument `dispatch` like this

```
function requestSignInFailure(error) {
  // save error message into state in reducer
  function(dispatch){
      dispatch({
        type: 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN_FAILURE'
        payload: error
      })
  }
}
```

it is same if you pass function directly in `connect` like so:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, {
   (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN_FAILURE'
        payload: error
      })
   },
   (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS'
        payload: success
      })
   }
})(Component);
```

and to change isLoading value you can use `componentDidMount`, and dispatch action inside componentDidMount inside it to change isLoading , it will dispatch action while component renders (mounts) like so:

```
function changeLoading(){
    function(dispatch){
        dispatch({
           isLoading: false
        })
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.props.changeLoading();
}

export default connect(null, changeLoading)(Component)
```

[react docs about lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 0):

i had made some changes to above code. requestSignInFailure and requestSignInSuccess in requestSignIn fine you can use it, or you have the choice to change thunk request to RSAA request but connecting it to firebase may be difficult.

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

export function requestSignIn() {
  // start sign in function
  startedRequestForSignIn()
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
    .then(response => {
      // success, so call requestSignInSuccess() to change state
      requestSignInSuccess(response.user);
    })
    .then(()=>{
        endedRequestForSignIn()
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // fail, so call requestSignInFailure() to change state
      requestSignInFailure(error);
    })

}

function requestSignInSuccess(user) {
  // save user info into state in reducer
  return {
    type: 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS'
    payload: user
  }
}

function requestSignInFailure(error) {
  // save error message into state in reducer
  return {
    type: 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN_FAILURE'
    payload: error
  }
}

function startedRequestForSignIn{
  return {
    type: 'IS_LOADING'
    payload: true
  }
}
function endedRequestForSignIn{
  return {
    type: 'IS_LOADING'
    payload: false
  }
```